# Rails loads data out of nowhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have a strange problem, appreciate if you help me.

I get two copies of rails projects - one runs in the Internet, and one - on my local machine (for developing, of course). First copy use production database, second - development (by myself cloned it from the production db).

And the strange thing - on one of the pages I have block that visible on Internet-running server, and non-visible on my local machine. It loads out of nowhere!

```
$cat app/views/home.html.erb:

....
<%= render 'shared/disclaimer' %>
....
```

okay.. we need to go deeper..

```
$cat shared/_disclaimer.html.erb::

<% if @disclaimer.present? %>
  <div class="disclaimer">
    <%== @disclaimer %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

tried to find source by searching whole folder for matching words from the block - no results.

Comment: same database engine?

Comment: @inye, yes, Postgres

Comment: Consider changing this `@disclaimer` into a nice helper method that you can write specs for a lot easier.

Comment: and the value of `@disclaimer.present?` is the same?

Comment: @inye, i opened both of db in pgAdmin4 - where can i check that value? maked printscreen here - http://hkar.ru/LCYk

Comment: you can check in your rails controller some like `puts @disclaimer` and see the output in your console, where you start the server (`rails server`)

Comment: in pgadmin you need to search in the table where is the @disclaimer